# How to get value from one textbox to another

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have two table being populated by different queries accurately. Say:

```
TableA
Col1   Col2   Col3        Col4
Val     Val  TblBColAVal   Val

TableB
ColA
Val
```

I want to get the value in textbox TableB ColA to textbox in TableA Col3.

I have tried report variables, parameters, and direct reference from txtboxA (ReportItems!txtbxB.Value) which resulted in the error:
Report item expression can only refer to other report items in the same group.

I am running out of Google leads on what I thought would be a straight forward assignment so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
JB

> EDIT More Info
>   Table A has information about a message/note a person sent.
>   Table B has who the message went to if applicable.

Msg sent options are everyone, organization, or specific person. This is all stored in the db table that populates tablix A. However if the note was sent to specific person mgmt wants a list of all persons it went to. So for the tablix A field in question I have (superfulous removed for reading):

```
=IIf(Fields!Sent_To.Value = "Specific Recipient", Variables!ToArrayList.Value, Fields!Sent_To.Value)
```

The point of this is to display everyone, org etc...UNLESS they chose specific person. In that case grab the field from tablix 2.

Now in tablix 2 I am taking the note id (a guid) and querying another db table for the recipients. I then stuff the result set into an array and concatenate a comma in between. Ideally this would then be used by tablix A IIF statement when appropriate. Tablix B is NOT visible. Here is that code:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ActionNoteID.Value, Fields!ActionNoteID.Value, Fields!FullName.Value, "ActNoteRecipients"), ",")
```

So to answer the question I did try to populate a variable but it was not happy accessing report fields. My variables was at the report level...only kind I know of.

I thought about doing this in SQL with a sub-query for the concatenation part. but figured this way would be easier...now I'm not so sure.

Anyway Ultimately this is what I want for a report

```
Msg Date | Msg Subject | Msg From | Msg To        | Msg Body
1/1/2000 | TEST        | JAMES    | Org           | Hello World
1/1/2000 | TEST2       | JAMES    | All           | Hello World2
1/1/2000 | TEST3       | JAMES    | Joe,Frank,Sam | Hello World3
1/1/2000 | TEST4       | JAMES    | Org           | Hello World4
1/1/2000 | TEST5       | JAMES    | Sally,Jane,Joe| Hello World5
```

Comment: Why can't you get the value in the sql step ? If you can't, you could load your value in a variable : @temp -> available values -> your query.

Comment: What does the underlying data used to get your final result look like? Assuming you'd still like to do this at the report level, can you add the `Join`/`Lookup` statement into the first `IIf` statement?